# How to design a Bandstop and Bandpass filter using Butterworth using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter

I went over and over again with MATLAB Help and google but couldn't find any solution.

First of all, designing the bandstop filter, the help says :

type:'stop' for an order 2*n bandstop digital filter if Wn is a two-element vector, Wn = [w1 w2]. The stopband is w1 < w < w2.

Does that mean when i design my bandstop filter, the code should be :

```
[B,A] = butter(2*N,Wn);  OR  [B,A] = butter(N,Wn);`
```

where the order `N` is given by user during runtime and `Wn` is calculated using `buttrod` function with known parameters.

Second of all, according to the help, only 3 types can be used to design a butterworth filter (low,high,and stop) , How do i design a bandpass filter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [B,A] = butter(N,Wn) means you will have 2*N poles/roots/.... and usually 2*N+1 terms in both B and A. Note that the poles are complex conjugates, so if you want 10 poles, N = 5....
2. The documentation is confusing... you can have all 4 filer types:

   ```
   [B,A] = butter(N,Wn, 'type');
   ```

where type = 'stop', 'bandpass', 'low', 'high'

Comment: A followup.. I tried it using 'bandpass' and 'stop' it gives an error :For the 'bandpass' filter option, Wn must have 2 elements.

How could that be solved

Comment: just like stop, you need `Wn = [w1 w2]` with the passband being w1 < w < w2.

Comment: I adjusted the code to handle both (low, high) and (bandpass and bandstop) seperatly. but when it comes to run either bandpass or bandstop, using Fpass = [0.2 0.25] and Fstop = [0.5 0.6], it gives me an error : The passband and stopband cutoff frequencies should not overlap... Its not overlapping , i dont understand